# subtract two values from two tables when null values exists

Tags: mysql

```
select p.partnerid,
sum(case when c.amount is not null then c.amount else 0 end) as amount,
sum(case when c.netamt is not null then c.netamt else 0 end) as total,
sum(case when (c.netamt - d.paidamount) is not null then (c.netamt - d.paidamount) else 0 end) as remainingamount,
sum(case when d.paidamount is not null then d.paidamount else 0 end) as paidamt
from customerinfo c
left join dailypayments d on c.accno = d.accno
right join partnerinfo p on c.partnerid = p.partnerid
where (d.paiddate is null or (d.paiddate >= '2011-3-15' and d.paiddate <= '2012-6-13')) and  p.manager = 7 group by p.partnerid
```

from athe above query i need to subtract two values from two tables where there is no value in second table.

for better understanding see below image.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function to remove the `case` and simplify your calculation:

```
sum(c.netamt - ifnull(d.paidamount, 0)) as remainingamount,
```